# Salt Stack file.recurse Recurse Failed

Tags: saltstack

I built a state file in salt to copy a list of check_mk Nagios scripts down to the remote server.  Below is a snip of the state file.

```
check_mk_defined_checks:
  file.recurse:
    - name: /usr/lib/check_mk_agent/local
    - source: salt://{{ slspath }}/files/cmk_checks
    - user: nagios
    - group: users
    - file_mode: 754
    - dir_mode: 755
    - require:
      - check_mk_agent_installed
```

The funny thing is, when I run the sls state directly everything works.  See below.

```
    salt-call state.sls dev.roles.srvr.system_conf.check_mk    
----------
                  ID: check_mk_defined_checks
            Function: file.recurse
                Name: /usr/lib/check_mk_agent/local
              Result: True
             Comment: The directory /usr/lib/check_mk_agent/local is in the correct state
             Started: 20:54:29.105625
            Duration: 1475.026 ms
             Changes:
```

However, when I run it as apart of a highstate I get the following error.

```
----------
          ID: check_mk_defined_checks
    Function: file.recurse
        Name: /usr/lib/check_mk_agent/local
      Result: False
     Comment: Recurse failed: none of the specified sources were found
     Started: 20:45:19.369238
    Duration: 917.113 ms
     Changes:
```

I have spent way to much time working on this.  I can not use the recurse function in any state or I get the same results.  It works when you call the state directly but not as apart of a highstate.

Any help anyone can provide would be great.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried hardcoding the `{{ slspath }}` part?

Comment: Yes.  If I hardcode the path it will work.  However, that solution will not work for me because I have 3 environments, dev, test, and prod.  Each environment has their own path.  Thus the reason I have the {{ slspath }} jinja variable specified.

Answer (score 3):

The source `files/cmk_checks` needs to be present in all environments and the paths on the master will be environment specific.

It's likely your `salt-call` run is executing the state in different environment than your highstate. You should run `salt-call state.sls` with [`saltenv=…`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.state.html#salt.modules.state.sls) argument.

Comment: holee crepe thank you so much.  I so often have doubts about using saltstack...  this solution even worked on 2015.5.10 (Lithium),